# Why does Django give a warning about unapplied migrations and how to fix it?

Tags: python, django

I started learning Django and i find a warning message: " You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.". What is the reason behind this warnings

Just want to know this

Comment: what does this error implies, start from there

Comment: Whenever you make changes to the models you should run the command the interpreter just showed you in order for the model (the representation of the entity of a DB entry in python object's world) to be in line with actual entities in the DB. Otherwise it might run ok, but it might fail as well. Take a look at the docs / it should be mentioned in the tutorial you are following.

Comment: @Gameplay As far as I know, only if you make changes to database fields and related entities (such as choices for choicefields). You can add or modify methods on the model without migrating (and makemigrations will say that there's nothing to do in such a circumstance).

Answer (score 0):

Every time you modify a model, you should execute `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`. Make migrations creates one or more migrations in `<app>/migrations`, where `<app>` is the app which defined the changed model.

If you import a package or an app from some other Django project, its migrations won't have been applied on your database. Ditto, if you move from accessing one database to another.

`./manage.py showmigrations` will show you your migrations, IIRC including unapplied ones. `./manage.py migrate` ought to fix the warning by making the database compatible with the migrations.

For more information, [consult the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/).

Answer (score 0):

django has pre-insTalled APPS like **admin, auth, contenttypes, contenttypes and ...** (you can see them inside `settings.py` file in **INSTALLED_APPS**) with their own `models`, and to use them you need to run `py manage.py makemigrations` to apply the pre-installed apps database queries and it will create tables inside the **sqlite3** file.